# Circle geometry QS

Tags: geometry

If a cone with a slant height equal to the diameter of the base is inscribed in a sphere with a radius of 10, what is the volume of the cone?

A. $375\pi$

B. $300\pi$

C. $250\pi$

D. $200\pi$

E. $160\pi$

Looks like the diameter and the slant heights of the cone would form an equilateral triangle. I used such a relationship but then I can't seem to get the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When viewed along a diameter as line of sight we have an equilateral triangle.

$$ Vol= \frac13\cdot \pi (5 \sqrt3)^2\cdot 15 = 375 \pi$$

Option A.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple question.

Hints: Use radius of sphere as the distance between the equilateral triangle's centroid and the vertices of equilateral triangle.Giving you radius 
$$r=10 \times \cos 30^o$$
$$r=5\sqrt{3}$$
$$diameter=slant (L)=10\sqrt{3} units$$

Now, height of cone(h) can be solved via: $L^2-r^2=h^2$
$$h=15 units$$

Now apply $$Volume=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h$$ To get $375 \pi $ units as answer